# What are some system of equations that cannot be solved like the quintets?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, computability

Abel-Ruffini says that there is no closed form solution for $5$'th degree polynomials. I am interested in which cases something like this occurs. Suppose we have a bunch of polynomial equations with parameters, when can we find the solutions for given parameters? So the quintent situation has one polynomial equation, 6 parameters and 1 unknown

$$a_6 x^5 + a_5x^4 + a_4 x^3 + a_3 x^2 + a_2 x + a_1 = 0$$

**Attempt to generalise**

Suppose we have a bunch of polynomials $f_1, ..., f_n: \mathbb{Q}^m \to \mathbb{Q}$ with $k$ parameters. Is there a computable function that assigns to $(a_1, ..., a_k)$ the Gödel number of some computable function which enumerates all $(x_1, ..., x_{m - k})$ such that $(a_1, ..., a_k, x_1, ..., x_{m - k})$ is a zero for all $f_i$'s?

**Actual question**

Are there techniques to answer this question negatively if you have explicit examples of $f_1, ..., f_n$, for example by reducing it to a problem which is known to be unsolvable? For high enough degree polynomials like

$$a_1 x_1^5  - a_1 x_1 - a_2 = 0 $$

$$x_6^2 + x_2 = 0 $$

this is easy by reducing it to a fifth degree polynomial equation (take $a_1 = a_2 = 1$, then it gives you a closed form for the solutions of $x^5 - x - 1 = 0$), but what if the degree is low like

$$xy = 1$$

$$xzk + 5 - 8dj = 0$$

$$abc + xy - 8d = 0 $$

?

Comment: Abel-Ruffini does not say there are no closed form solutions, it says there are no solutions in radicals.

Comment: How do you propose to enumerate an irrational $x_i$?  Or are you restricting to rational $x_i$?

Comment: For a system of equations, you can use Groebner bases.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Right, thanks. And yes, rational $x_i$ only. Are you saying that Groebner bases allow the question to be answered affimitavely? It solves the membership problem, but I don't see how it can be used to solve for the variety of an ideal. How would that work with $I = \langle a - b - cde, f + be - cge \rangle$ for example? (Is already a Groebner basis)

Comment: For that example, you can take arbitrary $b,c,d,e,g$ and solve for $a$ and $f$.

Comment: For rational solutions, Abel-Ruffini is not particularly relevant.  More to the point are such things as Faltings's theorem (the Mordell conjecture).